# Send packet to network device from char* buf in kernel with sk_buff

Tags: c, linux, networking, kernel

I have collected char * buffer from sk_buff  (hook packet and went through skb->head to skb_>end), transmitted this buffer to another PC. And now i want to resend this packet to network from a new PC. How can I send it? With using dev_queue_xmit() I had to reconstruct sk_buff structure from char* and data length. It is possible? Or can I use raw socket to resend my data?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to *construct* `sk_buff`, *not* reconstruct. Plus I don't think it's a reasonable idea to ever collect the `char*` from it.

The `sk_buff` simply represents a stream of bytes composed of separate pieces so they don't have to be copied all over the place when composing the packet. You should not collect a single buffer from `sk_buff`, but if you have single buffer, just fill in new `sk_buff` with one part pointing to the buffer and you are done.

Comment: I must resend my packets on a new side, that's why i transfer data+headers...now I think how can I do it, do I need one buffer or different char* buffers for payload and headers